# Using write.xlsx to replace an existing sheet with R package xlsx

Tags: java, r, excel, overwrite, r-xlsx

I am using  package `xlsx` Version:0.5.7 Date: 2014-08-01. in R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport" Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit).

I have an xlsx file with at least 2 sheets (say A and B). I need to read data from A, edit them and save them in B. This has to be done on a periodical base.

I am able to read data from A with `read.xlsx`. After editing the data frame I want to save it in an existing sheet B in the same xlsx file.

I try with this line

```
write.xlsx(down, paste0(root,'/registration reports/registration complete_WK.xlsx'), sheet="data_final", col.names=T, row.names=F, append=T, showNA=F)
```

but it give me this error:

```
Error in `.jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet", ` : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name
```

I need to replace that existing sheet multiple times. How can I do that?

Comment: Here is example, go to bottom of the article: https://danganothererror.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/write-data-frame-to-excel-file/

Comment: I don't think `write.xlsx()` will overwrite an existing worksheet.  Can you read the entire `.xlsx` file in and re-write all of the worksheets, including whatever the new sheet you need?

Comment: We don't usually support "fixing" things on obsolete versions of R.  Any reason you can't update to 3.1.2 and matching packages?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft A few versions later, the "problem" still exists. It's not a bug, but a desired behaiviour that prevents you from overriding your sheets

Answer (score 25):

If you want to save your new dataframe in an existing excel file, you first have to load the xlsx-file:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
```

which sheets you have you'll get like this:

```
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
```

you can easily remove and add (and thus replace) sheets with:

```
removeSheet(wb, sheetName="Sheet1")
yourSheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="Sheet1")
```

than you can fill the sheets with dataframes:

```
addDataFrame(yourDataFrame, yourSheet, <options>)
addDataFrame(anotherDataFrame, yourSheet, startRow=nrow(yourDataFrame)+2)
```

and last step is saving the whole workbook as .xlsx:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file)
```

btw: the documentation of the xlsx-package is really good and helpful on such questions :) 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just use openxlsx as it provides functions to edit an existing sheet?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the Java installed on your computer is incompatible with the xlsx library. The following thread discusses a similar issue with regard to the same package:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325744/r-xlsx-package-error)

Alternatively, your issue may be solved by a different Excel-related package, such as XLConnect. See this post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your post.  In the event that your links change or become unavailable, your answer will not be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not with R package xlsx but with the alternative R package **openxlsx**, which has an "overwrite" option:

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(yourdataframe, file = "~/yourexcelfile.xlsx",
sheetName = "yourexcelsheetname", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: This option overwrites the file, not only the sheet. Careful because it may be a loss of information