# R xlsx package error

Tags: java, r

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block
```

Does anyone have this error when you try to use

```
dat <- read.xlsx("data.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, colIndex=colIndex, rowIndex=rowIndex)?
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Having the same problem. Taking the same course :) Too bad the those Coursera instructors from JH don't seem to have much time to update slides or correct questions. The solution by @Deep-B fixed my problem. The download must corrupt the file somehow so it can't be read properly. Using WB fixed it.

Comment: @user3758532 - Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing this with `tabulizer()` in `R`

Answer (score 53):

I had this problem with a file downloaded from the internet using R command line, for an online course. Found that apparently the download mode needs to be set properly as write-binary (wb) since xlsx is basically a binary file (zip). Who knew?

If that's what you did too, re-download the file with the mode set properly; like:

```
download.file(fileUrl, destfile='./data/sample.xlsx', mode='wb')
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of java you have installed is likely incompatible with the xslx package. Try replacing your default java with the 64 bit version: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml.