# Update a single sheet in a workbook

Tags: r, excel

I like using Excel as a poor man's database for storing data dictionaries and such, because Excel makes it super easy to edit the data in there without the pains of installing a RDBMS.

Now I hit an unexpected problem. I can't find a simple way to rewrite just one of the worksheets, at least not without reading and writing the whole file.

```
write.xlsx(df,file ="./codebook.xlsx",sheetName="mysheet",overwrite=F)
```

Complains file exists. With `overwrite=T`, my sheets are lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using write.xlsx to replace an existing sheet with R package xlsx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053185/using-write-xlsx-to-replace-an-existing-sheet-with-r-package-xlsx)

Comment: You have several options available to you . . . 


library(xlsx) #load the package
# we'll assume your spreadsheet will be 20 rows & 8 columns
m <- (matrix('',nrow = 20,ncol = 8)) # '' removes NA from your final spreadsheet
# place values in specific cells 
m[10,2] <- c("B10") # as B10 is in row 10 and column 2
m[20,8] <- c("H20")
# export as xlsx
write.xlsx(x = m, file = "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files/Book1.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)


********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********  ********

Comment: Also . . .



library(xlsx)
# load file contents
file <- "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files/Book1.xlsx"
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[[1]]  # or another
# data to put into B10:H20 range
data <- matrix(runif(7*11), nrow=11, ncol=7)
# modify contents
addDataFrame(data, sheet, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE,
    startRow = 10, startColumn = 2)
# save to disk
saveWorkbook(wb, file)

Comment: One more . . . 

library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/excel_files/Book10.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")

# here, you can set the startRow and startCol. Col A = 1, B = 2,...
writeWorksheet(wb,x,"Sheet1",startRow = 10, startCol = 3, header = TRUE)

# automatically adjust column width
setColumnWidth(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", column = 3:4, width = -1)
saveWorkbook(wb)