# Add sheet to Excel file

Tags: r

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. I want to save a data frame and insert it into the file as the first sheet. How can I do this with the xlsx package?

Comment: I use `openxlsx` and the functions `loadWorkbook` and `addWorksheet`. Check the documentation to see if may help https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple excel worksheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: I don't think it's quite a duplicate, because the OP here is asking how to insert the sheet at the first position. The method in the linked question inserts new sheets at the last position. I'm not sure how to change the sheet order with the `xlsx` package. However, the `openxlsx` package has a `worksheetOrder` function that might be useful here.

Answer (score 26):

@Navid's answer is correct for the package `xlsx`, but unfortunately it has a java dependency which caused me to run into a lot of problems when reading/writing large amounts of data (10,000+ rows, so not even that large!).

I would recommend using the `openxlsx` package, which avoids the java dependency. If you want to add further worksheets to a single file then this is the approach I find works for me. @eipi10's comment about `worksheetOrder()` is a good tip, but you would need to alter that argument each time with something like `rev(1:3)` (assuming you had three worksheets in the file).

For clarity, here is the workflow for `openxlsx` version 4.0

```
# Create a blank workbook
OUT <- createWorkbook()

# Add some sheets to the workbook
addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet 1 Name")
addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet 2 Name")

# Write the data to the sheets
writeData(OUT, sheet = "Sheet 1 Name", x = dataframe1)
writeData(OUT, sheet = "Sheet 2 Name", x = dataframe2)

# Reorder worksheets
worksheetOrder(OUT) <- c(2,1)

# Export the file
saveWorkbook(OUT, "My output file.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is a nice summary of how to deal with writing multiple worksheets. You have to create the workbook object, add all sheets and then write it out. Because I needed to add to an existing file I had to read xlsx file, add worksheet, save. When I did some more processing I have to again read - add - save. Morale of the story: be aware it is not possible to add worksheets without reading in the whole file first (i.e. creating a wrokbook object - in your case empty, or in other cases - read from disk).

Answer (score 13):

It is an old post and late answer, but I am writing to help others when this search result pops up.

It is possible to write in separate excel sheets, but you need to write the write.xlsx() multiple times and each time use the option, `append=TRUE`
like this:

```
write.xlsx(df$sheet1, file = "myfile.xlsx", sheetName="sh1", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(df$sheet2, file = "myfile.xlsx", sheetName="sh2", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(df$sheet3, file = "myfile.xlsx", sheetName="sh3", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Be aware that this works with the xlsx package and not the openxlsx package

Comment: Is it possible to choose the position at which to insert the sheet ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add a data.frame in a new 'sheet' in an existing Excel file,
the answer of Navid is valid. Here another example. 
[R: Append a worksheet to an excel workbook without reading the entire workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181980/r-append-a-worksheet-to-an-excel-workbook-without-reading-the-entire-workbook)

In brief:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(your_dataframe, "test.xlsx", sheetName="New_Sheet", append=TRUE)
```

Where "your_dataframe" is your dataframe, "test.xlsx" is the path to your existing Excel file, and "New_sheet" is the name for the new datasheet you want to add to your existing Excel file.