# R inserting a new excel sheet between an existing excel workbook using R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

If I have an excel workbook in R called "wb" and in that workbook I have two sheets one called sheet A and one called sheet C . If I want to create a new sheet that will go between A and B called C  how would I do that ?

Comment: I know the function `worksheetorder` can be used to swap sheet place, and `writeData()` has and argument to specify the index where the sheet you write should be. But I don't know if it works with names instead of index. Anyway, you can do `writeData(wb = data, sheet = 2)` to write a new sheet between 2 sheets that alrdeay exist

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731382/add-sheet-to-excel-file)  or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181980/r-append-a-worksheet-to-an-excel-workbook-without-reading-the-entire-workbook) or [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/08/creating-excel-workbooks-with-multiple-sheets-in-r/) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\output.xlsx"
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\test_File_2.xlsx"
path_Excel_File2 <- "D:\\test_File_1.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)

xlWbk1$Worksheets(1)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(1))
xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
xlWbk1$Close()
xlWbk2$Close()
xlApp$Quit()
```