# How to export multiple objects into a single Excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, list, object, dataframe

I have created 7 different objects in R which contain 'vs' analysis. Now I want to get that info exported in the form of an Excel file.

I exported a csv file with different column names then I selected two columns and used `agevsmailtime<-table(data$Age,data$mailtime)` command which returns a result in this form :

```
data<-data.frame("Under 18 years old"=c(2,1,0,17,2,2),
"18 to 24 years old"=c(7,16,4,145,40,8),
"25 to 34 years old"=c(22,61,25,495,154,29),
"35 to 55 years old"=c(20,48,15,417,184,34),
"56 years or older"=c(12,10,4,85,39,9),
row.names=c("0 to 2000","10000 to 15000","15000 to 20000","2000 to 5000","5000 to 10000", "More than 20000"))
```

Now I made these 7 matrices like this and put them in a List object using

```
 l = list(agevsmailtime, agevsonlineavg, gendervsmailtime, gendervsonlineavg, languagevsmailtime, languagevsonlineavg)
```

Now I want to export all these object into an Excel file which I am not able to do

Comment: What sore of `objects` are they? Please try to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Updated question,please check now

Comment: Could you again elaborate a bit more. The `data` you provided does not have the `mailtime` nor the `onlineavg` nor `gender` info and so on. It would be great if you could provide the output of `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Also have a look at this, it might be what you are interested in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets