# Export data frames in list to xlsx with named sheets

Tags: r, list, openxls

I need to create an xlsx file with my list of data frames. I came across this solution [openxlsx solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets#), see below (or 5th Answer by Syed). However, my list has 51 named data frames, what changes do I make to below for a long list of data frames? Because my created excel file is not opening.

```
require(openxlsx)
list_of_datasets <- list("Name of DataSheet1" = dataframe1, "Name of Datasheet2" = dataframe2)
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets, file = "writeXLSX2.xlsx")
```

I tried to run write.xlsx(listname,file="") , the command ran successfully and created an xlsx file, but while opening it, it throws up an error "microsoft excel unable to open file because it is corrupt". I tried to shorten length of the vector down to 1-2, but it won't open.

EDIT: SOLVED BY HACK for now

```
#extract all data frames 
list2env(soup ,.GlobalEnv)
#reassign names and form new list 
list_of_datasets1 <- list("filename"=dataframe,.....)
#write new list
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets1, file = "template.xlsx")
```

Comment: Is each dataframe supposed to be a new sheet?

Comment: Yes it is, it's meant to be used as a data entry form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a workbook with multiple named worksheets, one must use `createWorkbook()`, `addWorksheet()`, `writeDataTable()`, and `saveWorkbook()` (in this order) instead of `write.xlsx()`.  Here is an example that generates worksheets based on a list of data frames that I create with random data.

```
library(openxlsx)
id <- 1:5
# create data frames
aList <- lapply(id,function(x){
   # generate output as list so we can use id as index to worksheets
   list( data.frame(matrix(runif(50),nrow=10,ncol=5)),x)
})
# initialize a workbook
wb <- createWorkbook("Workbook")
# add worksheets to workbook
lapply(aList,function(x){
     addWorksheet(wb,paste("worksheet",x[[2]])) 
     writeDataTable(wb,paste("worksheet",x[[2]]),x[[1]])
})
# save workbook to disk once all worksheets and data have been added
saveWorkbook(wb,file="./data/newWorkbook.xlsx")
```

...and the output, noting that there are 5 tabs in the workbook.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Len Greski . It's important for my named elements in the list to come out as sheet names, its like a form that needs to be filled, so the name of the form is important. I have managed to complete the task by an inefficient way for now. Please see my edit.

Comment: Dear Len, do you think there might be a similar solution [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78143875/16762740)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use append to create new sheets and name them as you want.

```
write.xlsx(datatable, file = "File.xlsx", sheetName = "sheet1", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the list names to the sheetName argument as a function:

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(datalist, file = "file.xlsx"),
                 sheetName = names(datalist), rowNames = FALSE)
```