# Renaming Excel tabs name using names from list of dataframe

Tags: r, xlsx

I am quite new to R and would require some advice.

I have exported a list of dataframes `final_data` into excel using the following code from `xlsx` package:

```
lapply(final_data,function(x){
  write.xlsx2(x,file = "Final.xlsx",sheetName = x,append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

However, my sheet name does not reflect the name of the corresponding dataframes from the original list. Instead, the sheet name became "Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2" etc. Is there something that needs to be changed to the above code? Would greatly appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets

Comment: Is it a named list? Interesting that code does not fail as you are passing dataframe objects (not strings) into sheet name?

Comment: @RonakShah Hi Ronak, yes I have tried the steps in the link, but it requires one command to append one individual dataframe to a new sheet. I was attempting to perform a loop that can do it for multiple dataframes

Comment: @Parfait Hi Parfait! I am able to type `View(final_data$Product)` and it will show me the dataframe, so yes it should be a named list

Comment: Try `writexl::write_xlsx` which directly writes several named sheets from a list of data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `lappy`, you lose the information of each elements' names. So you can keep this information first, and then loop through both data and name.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(xlsx)
name = names(final_data)
map2(final_data, 
     name, 
     ~write.xlsx2(.x, file = "Final.xlsx",
                  sheetName = .y, append = TRUE, 
                  row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Of course you can do this with `mapply` (or its wrapper, `Map`).

Comment: @Xinlu thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed