# R: write_xlsx with evaluation problem in argument

Tags: r, writexl

I have a loop like this:

```
library(writexl)
file_output="C:/test/test.xlsx"
for(i in 1:2){
    df<-iris[i,]
    write_xlsx(list(i=df),file_output)
    }
```

I would like to store each iteration in a separate sheet named the **value** of *i* (or in my real program: the value of some variable). Is this possible with write_xlsx, or in general, is it possible to make write_xlsx (or some other function) to interpret:

> "list(i=df)" as "list(1=df)" and "list(2=df)"

Comment: See here if your problem is how to save in multiple sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets

Comment: those are with java and perl dependent packages, I'm trying to distance myself from those.

Comment: There is also a solution for `writexl`: `sheets <- list("sheet1Name" = sheet1, "sheet2Name" = sheet2);
write_xlsx(sheets, "path/to/location")`

Comment: But there you have to hard code your sheet names, I'm wondering how I can use the value of variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `i = df` you must name the list elements. For your loop this would mean:

```
file_output = "C:/test/test.xlsx"
for(i in 1:2){
  df <- iris[i,]
  out <- list(df)
  names(out) <- i
  write_xlsx(out, file_output)
}
```

However, this will result in one file per data.frame, since `write_xlsx` does not append to existing files (at least to my knowledge). If you want to have only one file with sheets for the various data.frames, you'd have to adapt your code:

```
file_output = "C:/test/test.xlsx"
vars <- 1:2
out <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(vars))
for(i in vars){ # if you use variable names in vars, use seq_along(vars) instead of vars
  out[[i]] <- iris[i,]
}
names(out) <- vars
write_xlsx(out, file_output)
```

Since I do not see any merit in using a loop here, I'd even suggest to use `map` from the `purrr` package or `lapply`:

```
file_output = "C:/test/test.xlsx"
vars <- 1:2
out <- map(vars, ~ iris[.x,])
names(out) <- vars
write_xlsx(out, file_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop for this probably.

Just use `names()` on the `list` object `as.character()` in order to name the sheets.

```
l <- lapply(1:2, function(i) iris[i, ]) #creates separated df for each row
names(l) <- as.character(1:2) # sets the names of each element in the list
# these will be the sheets name


file="path_to_file.xlsx" # path to file name
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(l, file)
```