# I am not able to create new tab in Excel via R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I would like to create two tabs with Terms and Commloans.
But when I am using this code, Terms are overwriting Commloans and I don't have these two tabs :/

```
library("openxlsx")
write.xlsx(Comms, file = "PnL.xlsx", sheetName="Commloans", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(Terms, file = "PnL.xlsx", sheetName="Terms", append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to answer without a reprex, but I guess if you remove the `append = TRUE` from the first call and only leave it on the second, this should work using the `xlsx` package

So...

```
xlsx::write.xlsx(Comms, file = "PnL.xlsx", sheetName="Commloans")
xlsx::write.xlsx(Terms, file = "PnL.xlsx", sheetName="Terms", append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some worksheets first and *then* use `write.xlsx`. See this answer; 
[R: easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple excel worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets/50833546#50833546)

I would recommend using the `openxlsx` package

```
library(openxlsx)

# Create a blank workbook
OUT <- createWorkbook()

# Add some sheets to the workbook
addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet 1 Name")
addWorksheet(OUT, "Sheet 2 Name")

# Write the data to the sheets
writeData(OUT, sheet = "Sheet 1 Name", x = dataframe1)
writeData(OUT, sheet = "Sheet 2 Name", x = dataframe2)

# Export the file
saveWorkbook(OUT, "My output file.xlsx")
```