# exporting a list from R to excel in a good format

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to use the library(xlsx) to write some data from R into excel in a readable format.

My dataset is formatted as:

```
tbl <- list("some_name"=head(mtcars),"some_name2"=head(iris))
```

I would like to write this table to excel, with each item in the list being identified and the data being next to the item. E.g. the excel file should look like

```
"some_name" in cell A1

paste the dataframe head(mtcars) in cell A3

"some_name2" in cell A11

paste the dataframe head(iris) in cell A13
```

or something similar, e.g. pasting each item into a new worksheet.

Using

```
write.xlsx(tbl,"output.xlsx")
```

will output it correctly however it is not formatted in a readable way.

Any help would be great

Comment: [Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27713310/5325862) with 9 answers on writing a list of data frames to different sheets in the same workbook. I'm not finding an answer that also places a label text, but you could expand on those answers

Comment: Also, not sure if you're tied to using `xlsx`, but I've had an easier time building more complex workbooks with [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) instead. May just be personal preference though.

Answer (score 0):

The following codes create a xlsx file with multiple sheets, each of which holds a list name as the sheet name and a title, and a data frame below the title. You can modify it as you like.

```
require(xlsx)

ls2xlsx <- function(x, wb){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    sh <- createSheet(wb, names(x[i]))
    cl_title <- createCell(createRow(sh, 1), 1)
    addDataFrame(x[i], sh, startRow = 2, startColumn = 1)
    setCellValue(cl_title[[1, 1]], names(x[i]))
  }
}

tbl <- list("some_name" = head(mtcars),"some_name2"=head(iris))
wb <- createWorkbook()
ls2xlsx(tbl, wb)
saveWorkbook(wb, 'test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function writes a list of dataframes to an `.xlsx` file.
It has two modes, given by argument `beside`.

1. `beside = TRUE` is the default. It writes just one sheet, with the dataframe name on the first row, then an empty cell, then the dataframe. And repeats this for all dataframes, written side by side.
2. `beside = FALSE` writes one dataframe per sheet. The sheets' names are the dataframes names. If the list members do not have a name, the name is given by argument `sheetNamePrefix`.

The `.xlsx` file is written in the directory given by argument `file`.

```
writeList_xlsx <- function(x, file, beside = TRUE, sheetNamePrefix = "Sheet"){
  xnames <- names(x)
  shNames <- paste0(sheetNamePrefix, seq_along(x))
  if(is.null(xnames)) xnames <- shNames
  if(any(xnames == "")){
    xnames[xnames == ""] <- shNames[xnames == ""]
  }
  wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
  if(beside){
    sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = shNames[1])
    row <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex = 1)
    col <- 0
    for(i in seq_along(x)){
      col <- col + 1
      cell <- createCell(row, colIndex = col)
      setCellValue(cell[[1, 1]], xnames[i])
      col <- col + 2
      addDataFrame(x[[i]], sheet, 
                   startRow = 1, startColumn = col,
                   row.names = FALSE)
      col <- col + ncol(x[[i]])
    }
  }else{
    for(i in seq_along(x)){
      sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = xnames[i])
      addDataFrame(x[[i]], sheet, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  }
  if(!grepl("\\.xls", file)) file <- paste0(file, ".xlsx")
  saveWorkbook(wb, file = file)
}

writeList_xlsx(tbl, file = "test.xlsx")
writeList_xlsx(tbl, file = "test2.xlsx", beside = FALSE)
```