# openxlsx::write.xlsx overwriting existing worksheet instead append

Tags: r, data-munging, openxlsx

The `openxlsx::write.xlsx` function is overwriting spreadsheet instead of adding another tab.

I tried do follow some orientations of Stackoverflow, but without sucess.

```
dt.escrita <- format(Sys.time(), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

write.xlsx( tbl.messages
           ,file = paste('.\\2_Datasets\\messages_',dt.escrita,'.xlsx')
           ,sheetName = format(Sys.time(), '%d-%m-%y')
           ,append = FALSE)

write.xlsx( tbl.dic.dados
            ,file = paste('.\\2_Datasets\\messages_',dt.escrita,'.xlsx')
            ,sheetName = 'Dicionario_Dados'
            ,append = TRUE)
```

A spreadsheet with two tabs named: 30-07-19 and Dicionario_Dados.

Comment: You might be stuck first reading from that worksheet, `rbind`ing (or otherwise combining) old with new data, then go with the write. Related: https://community.rstudio.com/t/append-function-of-xlsx-in-openxlsx/9351/2

Comment: I don't know if `openxlsx` is in active development (several relevant bugs are going un-discussed/un-resolved), but this was requested in 2015 (https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/135). (In fact, awalker89 has been silent [since Oct 2018](https://github.com/awalker89).)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, you want to create one xlsx file with two tabs/sheets?
Then I usually first create the sheets and then write into each sheet seperatly (This is different from adding data to the same sheet by appending it).

```
library("openxlsx")
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "mtcars1")
addWorksheet(wb, "mtcars2")

writeData(wb, "mtcars1", mtcars1, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
writeData(wb, "mtcars2", mtcars2, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "excel_test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

**Update**:
Just wondering why I never used the `append` argument in `openxlsx` (which is my standard package for read/writing excel). It seems like there is no such argument to neither of the three functions `write.xlsx()`, `writeData()`, `writeDataTable()`. At least it's not in the documentation.

The function does not seem to throw an error when called with unknown arguments, for example the call below has a non-existing `somearg`, but returns no error.

```
write.xlsx(mtcars2,
           file = "excel_test.xlsx",
           sheetName = "mtcars1",
           somearg = TRUE)
```

**Update 2**
To append data to an existing table you could read in the number of rows of the existing worksheet, add +1 and use this values as startRow:

```
wb2 <- loadWorkbook(file = "excel_test.xlsx")

writeData(wb2,
          "mtcars1",
          mtcars2,
          colNames = FALSE,
          startRow = nrow(readWorkbook("excel_test.xlsx"))+1)
#Fixed the call to nrow, instead of ncol.

saveWorkbook(wb2, file = "excel_test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: after `saveWorkbook`, the column names disappeared from the file. I mean first row became empty, because the original file had column names.

Answer (score 0):

Write different dataframes to different sheets.

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(dataframe1, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1")
write.xlsx(dataframe2, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: This works for xlsx, but not for openxlsx as explained above. Openxlsx has the advantage it doesn't require Java to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a named list of dataframes:

```
library(openxlsx)

df_lst <- setNames(list(tbl.messages, tbl.dic.dados), as.list(c(format(Sys.time(), '%d-%m-%y'), 'Dicionario_Dados')))

write.xlsx( df_lst, file = paste0('.\\2_Datasets\\messages_',dt.escrita,'.xlsx') )
```

Answer (score 0):

The write.xlsx function of the xlsx package does have an append argument