# Download multiple dataframes in multiple sheets of the same excel file in a shiny app

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I wonderif there is a way to download 2 dataframes in the same excel file but in different sheet via shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Testing File upload"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("dl","Export in Excel")

    ),

    mainPanel(
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      paste0("df_dmodel", "_Table", ".xls")
    },
    content = function(file){
      tbl<-iris
      tbl2<-mtcars
      write.xlsx(tbl,tbl2 file, 
                 sheetName = "Sheet1", row.names = FALSE)

    }


  ) 

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can use `writexl::write_xlsx()` with a named list to output multiple sheets into an excel doc. Something like this can get your named list: `sheets <- ls(pattern = "tbl"); setNames(mget(sheets), paste0("sheet", seq_len(length(Sheets))))`.

Comment: how mtcars is included in this? could u provide a working example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple Excel worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: doesnt seem to work with downloadButton()

Comment: Can someone please help me solve an extension to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768707/how-to-download-multiple-editable-datatable-outputs-in-r-shiny-in-one-xlsx-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try changing your server code to this. Also, remember to open the app in your browser and not just the rstudio viewer (assuming your are using rstudio). Hope this helps!

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$dl <- downloadHandler(

        filename = function() {
            paste0("df_dmodel", "_Table", ".xlsx")
        },
        content = function(file){
            tbl<-iris
            tbl2<-mtcars
            sheets <- mget(ls(pattern = "tbl")) # getting all objects in your environment with tbl in the name
            names(sheets) <- paste0("sheet", seq_len(length(sheets))) # changing the names in your list
            writexl::write_xlsx(sheets, path = file) # saving the file
        }
    ) 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Andrew's answer using `write.xlsx` from openxlsx with a list of dataframes.

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton("dl","Export in Excel")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function() {
      "test.xlsx"
    },
    content = function(filename){

      df_list <- list(iris=iris, mtcars=mtcars)
      write.xlsx(x = df_list , file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  ) 

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```