# Writing R dataframes to excel files with multiple worksheets

Tags: r, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I am currently using `write_excel_csv2` from `readxl` to write a data.frame in R to an excel file.
How can I write two data.frames to two worksheets within the same excel file?
To give an example, how can I combine the following two files to one?

```
write_excel_csv2(mtcars[1:10,], file_name1)
write_excel_csv2(mtcars[11:20,], file_name2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write each DF to the same xlsx.file and specify different names for the worksheets. You have to use `append = TRUE` for the second worksheet.

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(mtcars[1:10,], file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1", row.names=FALSE)
write.xlsx(mtcars[11:20,], file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

This solution comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Answer (score 2):

`write_excel_csv2` just exports your data as a csv. If you want to export to excel have a look at `writexl` or `openxlsx` or ... packages, e.g. using `writexl::write_xlsx` you could do:

```
writexl::write_xlsx(list(sheet1 = mtcars[1:10, ], sheet2 = mtcars[11:20, ]), "mtcars.xlsx")
```