# Compare files in different folders in R

Tags: r

I am comparing files with same names in different folders which is easy if I just do it one by one. But how to compare multiple files in different folders with out doing it one by one. And write the output to an excel file in different sheets. such that abc-12.xlsx will contain 3 sheets where

```
sheet1= diff(~/my/path1/abc-12,~/my/path2/abc-12 )
sheet1= diff(~/my/path2/abc-12,~/my/path3/abc-12 )
sheet1= diff(~/my/path1/abc-12,~/my/path3/abc-12 )


I have files like below
    Path:~/my/path1/
    abc-12
    abc-34
    abc-45
    abc-56
    Path:~/my/path2/
    abc-12
    abc-45
    Path:~/my/path3/
    abc-12
    abc-45
    abc-56
```

#This is what I am trying

```
library(daff)
original <- list.files("~/my/path1/", ".tsv")
updated <- list.files("~/my/path2/", ".tsv")
edited <- list.files("~/my/path3/", ".tsv")

##Check if filename matches between two lists
check_updated <- basename(updated) %in% basename(original)
comp <- updated[check_updated]
if(comp == TRUE)
mapply(diff_data, original, updated)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple Excel worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: This doesnt. How to create diff of all the files.

Answer (score -1):

I would say convert all folders' file name data as list and then extract the common between.

```
get_list <- function(path){
  all_files <- c(paste0(path, list.files(path, recursive = TRUE)))
  all_files <- substr(all_files, nchar(path)+1,nchar(all_files))
  return(all_files)
}

Original <- get_list('/my/path1/foldername')
Updated<- get_list('/my/path2/foldername')
Edited <- get_list('/my/path3/foldername')

common_filenames <- intersect(intersect(Original,Update),Edited)
```