# How to use data from 2 different data frames to create an excel file with multiple sheets using R

Tags: r, purrr, openxlsx

With help from others here, I have working code to complete the task of splitting a dataframe by customer and writing the data to excel files with a dynamic number of tabs and with formatting applied.

I now have a second dataframe that is unrelated to the first but has a common customer identifier and I need to put the data for the matched customer onto its own sheet and save the excel file as one for the customer.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)


df.1 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period, ~cost1, ~cost2 , ~prod,
  'cust1',  '202201', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202202', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust1',  '202203', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust1',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202203', 5, 10,'online',
  'cust2',  '202204', 5, 10, 'in-person',
  'cust2',  '202202', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust3',  '202204', 5, 10, 'online',
  'cust4',  '202101', NA, NA, 'online',
  'cust4',  '202102', NA,10, 'online'
  
)

df.2 <- tribble(
  ~customer  ,~period1, ~period2, ~period3 , ~period4,
  'cust1', '202201' , '202202', '202203', '202204',
  'cust2', '202201' , '202202', '202203', '202204',
  'cust3', '202201' , '202202', '202203', '202204',
  'cust4', '202201' , '202202', '202203', '202204')
  

export_sheet <- function(wb, customer, data, sheet) {
  addWorksheet(wb, sheet)
  writeData(
    wb,
    paste0("Client Name: ", customer),
    sheet = sheet,
    startCol = 1, startRow = 3
  )
  writeData(wb, data, sheet = sheet, startRow = 6)
  addStyle(wb, sheet,
           cols = 3,
           rows = 6 + seq_len(nrow(data)),
           style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%")
  )
  addStyle(wb, sheet,
           cols = 4,
           rows = 6 + seq_len(nrow(data)),
           style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.0%")
  )
}

df.1 %>%
  split(.$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    wb <- createWorkbook()
    df %>%
      janitor::remove_empty(which = "cols") %>%
      split(.$prod) |>
      iwalk(
        ~ export_sheet(wb = wb, customer = nm, data = .x, sheet = .y)
      )
df.2 %>% # **this would be a different dataframe that needs added to a tab in the same excel file**
  split(.$customer) %>%
  iwalk(\(df, nm) {
    df %>%
      iwalk(
        ~ export_sheet(wb = wb, customer = nm, data = .x, sheet = .y)
    saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(nm, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
  })
```

The goal is to have one excel output file for each customer with tabs that include data from both dataframes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple Excel worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets) - save them in a list and pass the list to `openxlsx::write.xlsx()`

Comment: I dont think so.  The examples that looked similar required specifying which dataset went to which sheet.  I will look into using a List though and see if that might work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47053853/3358272 (one of the later additions to the above link) demonstrates this using a named list with `writexl::write_xlsx`; the use of names doesn't seem onerous, and frankly you can fake it using `setNames` and/or many other methods.

Comment: A few packages have been mentioned already. To add to those (this is also included in the duplicate link) is `rio::export_list`.